# How to save plots with opacity[0.5] with transparency?

Tags: plotting, opacity

How to save ParametricPlot with opacity[0.5] with transparency?

When I save the image the transparency is completely lot. in both pdf and eps files. I use

The following code for saving my parametric plot.

```
Export["path\\figure.eps",Show[figure], "EPS"]
```

Update: I tried getting pdf out (replacing eps with pdf), still no luck.

Comment: EPS format does not support transparency.

Comment: I am fine with any format eps or pdf

Comment: Can you get away with using SVG? It's also a vector format, but it seems like it supports transparency. I assume you prefer a vector image, but if you're okay with a rasterized image you could use PNG and just set the option `ImageResolution -> 300` or some larger number to get good resolution.

Comment: @MassDefect  Thank you so much. Yes PNG would do. And, it is almost working. But this added an opacity to the frame too making that lighter than other frames of other figures.

Comment: How are you adding in the opacity? If you just want the curves to be transparent, I would use something like `plot = ParametricPlot[..., PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]; Export["path\\figure.png", plot, Background -> None, ImageResolution -> 300]` (assuming you also want a transparent background; if not, leave out the part about background). This should result in only the curves being partially transparent and the frame being whatever you specified using `FrameStyle -> ...`.

Comment: ParametricPlot[....PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Black], Frame -> True]. This is how I am adding opacity.  I am doing exactly that. But, it makes the frame transparent.

Comment: @MassDefect again your suggestion is what I am using now. Instead of default frame style I used Black. And it turns black. Frame is still a bit different from the usual one but OK.